# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework re-create table using codefirst approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working in ASP.NET MVC. I created a table using Entity Framework code-first approach, but unfortunately I deleted the table. How can I re-create my table?

When I just want to recreate the table with the class it shows error

> dbo_Event does not exist and you don't have permission

Please help me.

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    //public string Speaker { get; set; }
    // public string Topic { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; } // This shows which type it belong to i.e
    public string Venue { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SuperVision { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Department { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Designation { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    //[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    //public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    //these are the link tables
    public int EvntID { get; set; }
    public int DepartID { get; set; }

    public int DesigID { get; set; }

    public string Speaker { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the action method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Event events, HttpPostedFileBase files)
{
        Event evnt = new Event();
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(files.FileName).ToUpper();

        if (ext == ".JPG" || ext == ".JPEG" || ext == ".PNG")
        {
            evnt.EventName = events.EventName;
            evnt.Category = events.Category;
            evnt.Date = events.Date;
            evnt.Venue = events.Venue;
            evnt.Description = events.Description;
            evnt.SuperVision = events.SuperVision;

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            //files.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);

            byte[] image = stream.ToArray();

            evnt.Image = image;

            evnt.StartDate = events.StartDate;
            evnt.EndDate = events.EndDate;

            db.Event.Add(evnt);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
}
```

Comment: please consider explaining more, like how was the table deleted, and why can't you just re add the class to your code and get the table created, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I got this on re adding the class.

"Cannot find the object "dbo.Events" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions."

Comment: i enabled the auto-migration to true. Is that the Problem? and I delete table from sql server object Explores

Comment: You need to share some code, like about how you initialize your context and which method you use.. also are you using migrations? if yes then you need to create a migration. My advice is read more about entity framework and check some tutorials, then you will either have your problem figured out or you will be able to describe it better

Comment: I updated My Post with code. @AKhudairy

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

go to the Nuget Package Manager --> package managment console
 1. enable-migration
 2. add-migration Initial
 3. update-database

Comment: so just add the initial migration and update the database